# send a URL as a variable to another URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

there is a div that i want to load a url in it with a fix url. i define a variable to add my url next to that page name. but the variable is not replace . and the url broke.
how can i send a url as a variable to another url

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var url = 'reservation/oneway/list.bc?bcpage=12&page=1&cat=130';
$('.load-face').load('/one-wayajax.bc?url='+url);
});
</script>
```

the result is :
**one-wayajax.bc?url=reservation/oneway/list.bc?bcpage=12&page=1&cat=130**
and removed the other objects because there is two ? repeat behind together.
i guess i have to use the second part as a variable

the true result should be this : ? &

**one-wayajax.bc?url=reservation/oneway/list.bc&bcpage=12&page=1&cat=130**

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question. Or doesn't it work? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent(myUrl)` to encode URL

Comment: @HassanImam how can i use encodeURIComponent in jquery function ? is this work only with javascript?

Comment: Every Javascript function will work with Jquery. Jquery uses Javascript.

Comment: @HassanImam i wrote this code bu not worked is it true?

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var url = 'reservation/oneway/list.bc?bcpage=12&page=1&cat=130';
$('.load-face').load('/one-wayajax.bc?url='+encodeURIComponent(url);

});
</script>